# shiny tables with more than one input

Tags: sorting, input, shiny

I would like to create shiny output table below data set with more than one input.
I would like to select model,segment and year. How can I do that? Is there a way that you put a button and also sort the data displayed? 
Thank you.

```
df=data.frame(year=c(2018,2018,2017,2017,2017),model=c("mazda","ford","ford"
,"toyotta","mazda"),segment=c("c1","ax","ay","gv","c1"),sales=c(23,54,65,78,54))
```

Answer (score 1):

The wonderful `library(DT)` fulfills all of the mentioned requirements without defining any inputs or custom filter logic:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("Car data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  df = data.frame(
    year = c(2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017),
    model = c("mazda", "ford", "ford"
              , "toyotta", "mazda"),
    segment = c("c1", "ax", "ay", "gv", "c1"),
    sales = c(23, 54, 65, 78, 54)
  )

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    df
  }, filter = "top", options = list(pageLength = 30))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you but year column  I can only see 20. How can I make it larger?

Comment: Not sure what you are aiming at? See attached screenshot.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about the displayed number of rows? You can set the pageLength option. Furthermore you can use the pagination buttons to navigate through your table. I edited my example to pageLength = 30 but in your provided data only 5 rows are available.